# Big O for this Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, analysis

What will be the Big O for this algorithm? To me, it looks O(n^3) `^` is exponent.

```
A()
{
    int i,j,k,n;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i^2;j++)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=n/2;k++)
            {
                statement ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't really evaluate the big O time of a routine which can't run due to syntax errors.

Comment: It appears that you are using `^` to refer to the exponent operator. Explicitly stating that will be helpful as `^` refers to XOR in C and your example appears to follow a C syntax.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is `O(n^4)`.

Explanation:

1st time, outermost loop runs, second loop runs `1^2` times and innermost for `n/2` times.

Overall `1^2 . n/2`

2nd time, outermost loop runs, second loop runs `2^2` times and innermost for `n/2` times.

Overall `2^2 . n/2`

......

Similarly till `n^2 . n/2` in the last iteration of `i`(outermost loop)

Sum them up : `(n/2)(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + .... n^2)`=`n/2.[n(n+1)(2n+1)/6]`  (Use the property of sum of squares of the first `n` numbers)

Which is `O(n^4)`

Comment: How could it be `n^2*n/2`
But, what about the first loop ?
Which makes it `n*n^2*n/2`

Comment: @Arif No Arif, realize that what I have written is for **each iteration** of `i`(outermost loop). In the last iteration, when `i` reaches `n`, the middle loop runs for `n^2` times and the innermost for `n/2` times. So, overall it is `n^2*n/2` **only for the last iteration**. Basically, I have broken down the problem into every single iteration of `i` and then adding them all up to get the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be `O(n^2*i^2)`. 
If `i^2 <= n`, it becomes `O(n^3)`.

L.E. I've just saw that you are using `i` in the first loop. In this case, `i <= n`, so it becomes `O(n^4)`.

Comment: The algorithm shows that `i <= n`, so I think `i^2 <= n^2` is more correct, resulting in `O(n^4)`.

Comment: @KyleA Yes, you're right. I didn't pay attention. It is O(n^4).

Answer (score 1):

The C operator ^ performs an xor, so the middle loop with exit on the second pass. That makes it's runtime constant.

The variable n is uninitialized, so we can't really say what the outmost or innermost loop will do.

If n is constant then the whole runtime is constant ( order of 1)
If n is passed in then the runtime is order of N squared, because the middle loop has constant time.